# Angular Role Based Protection from Client Side Question

Tags: angular, security, single-page-application, role-based

I am new to angular and have been googling about this but haven't really found anything helpful (probably my google terms I'm using).

In a traditional server side application, you can generate a page which has different controls/functions/layout/etc based on the authenticated user. Because this is all done on the server side, two different users (who see two different things) have no idea what the other user might see. Since it is all server side, no way to run fiddler or some other tool to extract all the typescript/javascript/html/etc.

> In angular, lets say you have routes for roles ClientRole => /pages/1,
>   /pages/2 AdminRole => /pages/1, /pages/2, /pages/admin/1,
>   /pages/admin/2
>
> For the routes, I am guessing you would just send a new route list
>   through an observable/ngrx store anytime the user auth changed to
>   update the list of routes (thus preventing someone from going through
>   the "routes file" to see there is a "/page/admin" route defined if
>   they aren't in a role that has that route)?
>
> How could this work with components? So that if someone were to try to
>   reverse engineer the client side components, they wouldn't even have
>   the "admin components" on the client side unless they were logged in
>   and in the admin role?

Comment: How are you letting users log in? If you're using jwt, then you can send information about privileges in your jwt token

Comment: yes, JWT for the token, but how to prevent the components they don't have access to from being loaded on the client side until they authenticate and confirm they are in a role for that component?

Answer (score 0):

Let your `jwt` token contain something like `level` that can be either "user" or "admin". Once they're logged in, you can call `isLoggedIn()` in your `guard` service.

So in your `auth.service.ts`:

```
private isLoggedInAs = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
isLoggedIn = this.isLoggedInAs.asObservable();

// check if user is logged in, and if so with what level
public isLoggedIn() {
    // insert relevant filters that will return false
    const jwtpayload = jwt.decode(this.getToken());
    this.updateLoggedIn(jwtpayload.level);
    return true;
}

updateLoggedIn(level: string) {
  this.isLoggedInSource.next(level);
}
```

And in your `guard.service.ts`:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
        this.router.navigate(['/pages']);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And wherever you need to know their level, you can do something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.isLoggedIn.subscribe(isLoggedIn => {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
        } else {
            this.isLoggedIn = 'anonymous';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How does this prevent the admin component from being sent from the server to the client when the angular app loads in the browser? I understand the guard will “block access” to the component but I don’t want the client side to have anyway of getting the component until after they login and have a role allowed for the client.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://angular.io/guide/universal